# How to set the value of custom node property from multiple sources?

Tags: node-red

I want to make a custom node in Node-RED where I have a property with preset values listed in a drop-down box.

Next, I want to add, as the last item in the drop-down, an "other" item where if it is selected, a text-box will appear and a custom value for the property can be typed-in.

So far, what I have is this:

```
<script type="text/x-red" data-template-name="new-node">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-input-name"><i class="icon-tag"></i> Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="node-input-property"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Key</label>
    <select type="text" id="node-input-property" style="width:70%;">
      <option value="value1">value 1</option>
      <option value="value2">value 2</option>
      <option value="value3">value 3</option>
      <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row" id="new-property" hidden>
    <label for="node-input-newproperty"> New Property</label>
    <input type="text" id="node-input-newproperty"
  </div>
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  RED.nodes.registerType("new-node", {
    category: "function",
    color: "#9dd4ae",
    defaults: {
      name: { value: "" },
      property: { value: "", required: true }
    },
    inputs: 1,
    outputs: 1,
    oneditprepare: function() {
      $("#node-input-property").change(function() {
        const selectedProp = $("#node-input-property").find(":selected").val();
        if (selectedProp == "other") {
          $("#node-input-newproperty").show();
        } else {
          $("#node-input-newproperty").hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

My problem is that I am unable to set the custom value to the property because of [this](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/properties#property-edit-dialog):

> For each of the properties in the defaults array, it looks for an <input> element with an id set to node-input-<propertyname>. This input is then automatically populated with the current value of the property. When the edit dialog is okayed, the property takes whatever value is in the input.

Because I am using a separate input object for the custom property value, the Node is unable to pick it up since I can't use the same ID ("node-input-property") for it.

Perhaps, is there a way to set the property value manually?
I tried using this code below but it didn't work...

```
this.property = $("#node-input-newproperty").val()
```

Comment: Where did you put that code? It should work in the `oneditsave` callback function

Comment: I tried on both `oneditprepare` and `oneditsave` but it isn't getting saved. Another problem is that when I re-open the node properties, the value I typed in the new `$("#node-input-newproperty")` isn't retained. Should I just make a different property for the "other" property and handle it in the js file? Tbh, I'm just asking this question to see if it could be done just in the html part.

Comment: Update: I tried using a different property name and it does get saved i.e. `this.property1 = $("#node-input-newproperty").val()` in oneditsave. Perhaps the automatic setting based on ID in oneditprepare is performed AFTER oneditsave? Because when I just use the "property" name, it still picks up "other" instead of the value from the text-box.